# Combine 2 models table data into 1 model (table),Django

Tags: django, django-models

models.py:

```
class NewJsonData(models.Model):
    speed = models.IntegerField()
    heading = models.IntegerField()
    altitude = models.FloatField()
    accuracy = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    altitudeAccuracy = models.FloatField(null=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    
    pass

class NewApiJsonData(models.Model):
    _id = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    coords = models.ForeignKey(
        NewJsonData, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    mocked = models.BooleanField()
    timestamp = models.FloatField()
    _v = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    createdAt = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    updatedAt = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
```

I was trying to create a new table having contents of both models as seen in below picture.[image]

Table of NewJsonData looks as:
[image]

and table of NewApiJsonData looks as:

[image]

Comment: perhaps give a reason why you want to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can inherit one model to another in django

```
class NewJsonData(models.Model):
    speed = models.IntegerField()
    heading = models.IntegerField()
    altitude = models.FloatField()
    accuracy = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    altitudeAccuracy = models.FloatField(null=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField()

class NewApiJsonData(NewJsonData): #inherit above model
    _id = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    coords = models.ForeignKey(
        NewJsonData, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    mocked = models.BooleanField()
    timestamp = models.FloatField()
    _v = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    createdAt = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    updatedAt = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
```

so the resulting NewApiJsonData contains the fields of NewJsonData

Answer (score 1):

These are classes. Use multiple inheritance, if you know there will be no conflicts:

```py
class Combined(NewJsonData, NewApiJsonData):
  pass
```

Comment: tried this but no info in Combined table

Comment: just 2 columns of each model is there when I given each model an autofield primary key so it could resolve this error  The field 'id' from parent model 'iliyas.jsondata' clashes with the field 'id' from parent model 'iliyas.apijsondata'. when I tried your way